# showing blank page to stop flicker until react gets data

Tags: reactjs

I've got a page that calls an api endpoint to get some data, and to see if they're logged in or not.

If I had session set to false in the constructor and whether or not there's a delay in fetching the data on componentDidMount, the conditional content for false shows up before the fetch comes back, sets session to true and show the content for true.

for now to hide that flickering, I've set session to null to render a blank page until the data comes back. is there a better way of doing this?

```
class Settings extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);   
        this.state = {
            session: ""
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // possible delayed fetch response
        this.setState({ session: true })
    }

    render() {
        const {session} = this.state;
        { 
            if (session === true) {
                return (<h1>logged in</h1>)
            } else if (session === false) {         
                return (<h1>not logged in</h1>)
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }   
    }
}

export default Settings;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set session to `null` in the constructor, and in render method show loading until session result is fetched. For a demo I added a timeout to show loading. Also unless for async state changes, try not to set state in `componentDidMount` as same can be achieved using `constructor`.

```
class Settings extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);   
        this.state = {session: null};
    }

    componentDidMount{
        setTimeout(() => this.setState({session: true), 500) // only to simulate fetching session data
    }  

    render() {
        const {session} = this.state;
        if(session === null){
          return <div>...loading</div>
        }
        if (session) {
            return (<h1>logged in</h1>)
        } 
        return (<h1>not logged in</h1>)
    }
}

export default Settings;
```

Comment: so do the fetch call in the constructor?

Comment: since fetching session info is async `componentDidMount` is the better place to fetch the data. Checkout https://daveceddia.com/where-fetch-data-componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount/

Comment: Yes as long as you are aware that you can set inital state in constructor rather than componentDidMount no problem. The only part I would change would be setting session to null rather than empty string.